# How do I search a list of specific member Id using examine manager in umbraco

Tags: umbraco, lucene.net, umbraco7, examine

Good Day!

How do I search a list of specific member Id using examine manager in umbraco.
My code shows like this:
 **ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["InternalMemberSearcher"].CreateSearchCriteria("member").NodeTypeAlias("member").Compile()**. I already get all the members, but I would like to get it with specific dynamic Id's. Any idea on how to get those specific member Id's?

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already resolved my problem by adding RawQuery. 
solution code provided.

ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["InternalMemberSearcher"].CreateSearchCriteria("member").NodeTypeAlias("member").RawQuery("Where id in (1,2,3,4)").Compile();

Thanks